# Strange javascript bug in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

[image: Here are results for the latest Chrome]

Looks like after several thousands of requests to Chrome to check the same expression value it changes the opinion :)

How could that happen?

Comment: Odd. I repeated this test twice and logged `typeof null == "undefined"` 100,000 times as well and got the exact same number of false's and true's both times. 12291 for false and 87709 for true.

Comment: My favorite comment regarding this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37986016/why-typeof-null-undefined?lq=1#comment63417079_37986016 .